# How to convert wiki answer to normal answer

Tags: support, answers, community-wiki

This is from question
[Multiple stdin/stdout actions during one process call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755791/multiple-stdin-stdout-actions-during-one-process-call) (and its answer)

The author @eridal wrote

> oops.. marked it as community wiki as error, any with enough rept
>   could move it back for me please? thanks! :)

I could  not find a way.  I marked it for moderator attention? Was the right thing? Is it really possible to convert an answer that was wiki to normal answer (considering conditions like

- single user edited
- Time stamp is less than 24 hours

Comment: OP edits the answer and unchecks 'community wiki' checkbox below the answer textarea.

Answer (score 9):

[Moderators can](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83373/245827), but chances are they won't because [you can still receive bounties on community wiki answers](https://meta.superuser.com/a/267/208601), so there's not much need for it, and they'll remember to be careful next time and not bother the mods.